# the meaning of 'respectability' here

Tags: word-meaning

From The Folded Leaf By William Maxwell

Mr. Peters was described:

> Time is probably no more unkind to sporting characters than it is to
>   other people, but physical decay ***unsustained by*** ***respectability*** is
>   somehow more noticeable.

Does the bold part here mean that he has not maintained respectable behavior or he has not gotten the respect from people?

Answer (score 1):

A person who is not middle or upper class or otherwise can be considered "respectable" will show their age more, even if not physically off worse than a respectable person.

Respectability specifically means someone of a certain class including a parson, a lawyer, a noble, etc. Someone who regularly bets on sports may not be considered of the same class / respectable. Someone very rich or in a ruling class would possibly be exempted.

Comment: The working class people can't be respectable?

Comment: @LucianSava That'll depend on the culture in the book.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're talking about the book's character specifically.+1